# Select Query using like clause in Sql server 2008

Tags: sql-server

```
Table name  : sp_text  
Column name : obj_Text
```

In this column, all the stored procedures are stored as text.

I need to retrieve all the stored procedures which has `raiserror` and **%d** in `raiserror`.

eg, A SP contains the following `raiserror` in it.

```
raiserror('quantity adjustment is not allowed in row no %d', 16, 1, @fprowno)
```

I tried the below query but couldn't arrive at the result.

```
select *
from   sp_text_ismail 
where  obj_Text like '%raiserror%'
  and  obj_Text like '%/%d%'
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the system view [sys.sql_modules](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175081.aspx): far simpler. And you can escape % with brackets in the LIKE

```
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(object_id), * FROM sys.sql_modules
WHERE definition LIKE '%raiserror%[%]d%'
```

You also can not select or filter on a stored procedure.

Comment: What does "You also can not select or filter on a stored procedure" mean?

Comment: You can't do this:  FROM (stored proce) WHERE (stored proc column) = foo

Comment: Do you mean that you can't put an `EXEC` inside a `SELECT` statement? (Which is true, but unrelated to the question.) Or that you can't filter stored procs based on their column names? (Which is related to the question, but false.)

Comment: @gabe: correct to both. I assumed that "sp_text" is a stored proc. Poor naming for a table... lordy lord.

Comment: Even worse, the OP uses `sp_text` in one place and `sp_text_ismail` in another.

Answer (score -1):

You have to use escape character '\' in your query and also mention it at the end. You have used forward slash instead of backward one. In fact you can use any character as escape char, but you have to mention at the end.

Try this query

```
select * from sp_text_ismail where obj_Text like '%raiserror%' and obj_Text like '%\%d%' ESCAPE '\'
```

Comment: ESCAPE stops the search and you can't query a stored proc

Comment: @gbn: Thanks for info. Can you pls give me any reference link for this fact? for my learning ..